# How to test method call from within another method using junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am new to unit testing in java so please excuse if this is a silly question. I have a method like the one below. What I want to do is verify that this method is being called and also check that the parameters that are passed are not null and also being called. How can I go about doing this in junit/mockito?

```
public <return type> callMe(Object objectA) {

if(objectA.name != null && objectA.age != null) {
someOtherMethod(objectA.name, objectA.age)

  }
}
```

Comment: Does calling `someOtherMethod` produce any effect that can be observed from outside the class under test? If yes - then you should be asserting on that publicly visible effect, rather than the fact that `someOtherMethod` was called, which is an implementation detail.

Comment: So do I need to make a `CallMe callMe = new CallMe` and then do something like `callMe.someOtherMethod` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one alternative is using `@Spy` annotation to execute the method inside your first method and after that check the result.
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy

You can also use the `Mockito.veify(...)` to check if the method was called.
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify